# Rails development - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I'm a Rails developer newbie using MySQL as the database. I can successfully connect to MySQL using the command:

```sh
    MySQL -u macDaddy -p
```

at the command prompt, so I know the user is valid and MySQL is running. But when I try to run

```sh
    rake db:schema:dump
```

at the command line I get this error:
rake aborted!
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Is something wrong with my database.yml? Here it is:

```yaml
    development:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      reconnect: false
      database: bookmobile
      pool: 5
      username: macDaddy
      password: booklover
      host: localhost
      socket: mysql
      port: 3306
```

I've also tried removing the port and socket lines but I still get the same error. Please help. Here are my versions:

- developing on Windows 7
- MySQL Ver 14.14 distrib 5.5.21 for win64
- Server version 5.5.21
- Rails 3.2.1

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you specify 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Is mysqld listening on 3306?  Try `netstat -an | grep 3306`.  If you don't see something like `*.3306 *.* LISTEN` then that could be the problem.

Answer (score 42):

My best guess is that the machine, which you indicated as Windows, has IPv6 networking enabled. Thus when you try to go to localhost, it is resolving to "::1". This is in fact the local machine, however, default MySQL installs normally have bind-address set to 127.0.0.1, which would cause localhost to fail in this setup.

You might be able to verify this by running `ping localhost` from the command prompt, and seeing if you get a response like:

```
 Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

To fix this, you can change your config to specify:

```
 host: 127.0.0.1
```

Alternately, you can change MySQL's configuration to allow a different bind-address, e.g. localhost instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: As a newbie it took me far too long to realize you first need to **install mysql community server separately** since it's not included in ruby on rails or ruby mine.

Comment: Furthermore the configuration file mentioned in this answer is located at config -> database.yml

Answer (score 6):

simply change your host to host:127.0.0.1

Answer (score 6):

Change the value of **host** in the **database.yml** to be **"127.0.0.1"** will work. Or,you can modify your pc's hosts file, add an item as "localhost 127.0.0.1".

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error but it was because the port: 3306 was missing  in the database.yml. Once I added port: 3306 issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't have password set in your database server(mysql), try this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: bookmobile
  pool: 5
  username: macDaddy
  password:
  host: localhost
  socket: mysql
  port: 3306
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure the port number that you have set while creating MySQL(e.g.: 7777), please add port number with appropriate 'username' and 'password'.

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: admin
  host: localhost
  port: 7777
```

in the database.yml in config directory of your app directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mysql server is running.