# When I run "rails s" from the command prompt, I receive a MySQL2::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to using Ruby on Rails to run a site. A little backstory:

So I'm working a project, and I've been given the code for the site. I'm running Windows, so I know that it's not the best OS for RoR, but switching to a different OS is a last resort for me.

I got the RailsInstaller from railsinstaller.org, and ran that. Everything installed smoothly.

I ran `bundle install` from my site's directory and ran into a problem with the gem "therubyracer". Did a bunch of searching for that, and found out that Windows doesn't need the gem. I think. So I commented out the gem in the Gemfile, and ran `bundle install` again. Everything installs fine.

I try to run `rails s` through the command prompt and received an error:

```
The program can't start because LIBMYSQL.dll is missing from your computer.
```

So I did a little research on that, and found out that I had to copy the file into the Ruby/bin folder under the RailsInstaller directory. The error went away.

Finally, I ran `rails s` again, and the server was put under the localhost. I think. Anyway, I went to `localhost:3000` and received a MySQL2::Error and `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`. When I click `Full Trace` I get the code:

```
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:303:in `new_connection'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:313:in `checkout_new_connection'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:232:in `loop'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:232:in `block in checkout'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `checkout'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `retrieve_connection'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__132547094__call__984979790__callbacks'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

I looked into this a bit and found [Rails development - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792862/rails-development-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061).

When I try `ping localhost` on my command prompt, I get what the top comment says:

```
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

And I'm not sure how to change the config to make the host 127.0.0.1.

Sorry that was kind of long, and I'm not sure how helpful it is. As I said in the title, I am VERY new to this - I'm still not sure what a `host` is.

I'm really just want to get the site running so I can finally start working on it. Am I doing everything right? Do I actually need `therubyracer`? What have I done/haven't done that will help me get it started? What problem is the error showing?

If there's anything else I need to provide, let me know! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have MySQL running on your local machine?  Also, does the configuration in `database.yml` (including database, username, and password) match your MySQL instance?

Comment: How you have created your project? did u just used scaffolding or you have copied part of the code from a book/tutorial?

Comment: Wow, you're really starting from bare bones.  A host is a computer that provides a service, e.g. a web server.  In this case, the host is your computer.  Web communications are done using IP addresses (which usually have domain names like example.com), and a special one, 127.0.0.1 is the IP address of the computer, and given the name `localhost`.  It is most likely that, as @PinnyM suggests, you need to have the database server MySQL running.  If you're just getting started, Rails also works with a simpler local database called SQLLite, which you might want to consider.

Comment: @PinnyM How do I tell if I have MySQL running? I did download the installer, and installed it. Does that mean it's running? Where would I find `database.yml`?

@stsd I forked the project code from github, and downloaded it to my computer using the github app. 

And what exactly is MySQL and SQLLite? What does it do? @tharrison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [MySQL workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to check the server status.

The configuration for the DBMS is set in the `db/database.yml` file of a Rails project.

I recommend you read up a bit about Rails, and about database storage in general.  You can start with [this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) which uses SQLite.  MySQL and SQLite are different flavors of [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) that Rails will typically use to store information that needs to persist for the long term.

Comment: Thanks for the links. =]

So, I did a reinstall of MySQL. When I check the workbench, it now says, Local instance MySQL55 in the left column. User is `root` and Host is `localhost:3306`. What should I put in the database.yml? More specifically, what should go in the "database:" field? I set the user to root and the password to what I defined it as.

Comment: You first need to create a database for your rails app.  You can use the workbench to create one (workbench calls it a 'schema').  Name it something like 'yourapp_development', where 'yourapp' is something you'll remember as associated with your app.  While you're at it make another database called 'yourapp_test'.  In database.yml in the development section set `database: yourapp_development` and in the test section set `database: yourapp_test`.

Comment: Alright, I've done this, and I've set all the fields in the `database.yml` to the correct settings. However, I'm still receiving the same error when I run `rails s` from the command prompt and try to connect to `localhost:3000`.  What else could I be missing/doing wrong?

Comment: In your database.yml file, try changing `host: localhost` to `host: 127.0.0.1`

Comment: There is no field for `host`. Should I create it under the development section?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that worked! I'm getting a different error now, `ExecJS::RuntimeError in Home#index` but that's probably unrelated. Thanks so much for your help!