# Ruby Mysql can't connect to localhost (10061)

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im following the ruby on rails course from Lynda, where I have problems connecting to the database using the command line in windows.

I can connect to the database using "mysql -u username -p" and entering the password afterwards. I can create databases and all without problem.

Now when executing:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

in my application folder "simple_cms" I get the following:

```
rake aborted!
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Running the trace gives:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\simple_cms>rake db:schema:dump --trace
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump
rake aborted!
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.
rb:44:in `connect'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.
rb:44:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connec
tion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/railti
es/databases.rake:379:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/railti
es/databases.rake:378:in `open'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.10/lib/active_record/railti
es/databases.rake:378:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block i
n execute'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute
'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block i
n invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_
with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `
invoke_task'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `
block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `
each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `
block in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `
run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `t
op_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `b
lock in run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `
standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `r
un'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>
'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\simple_cms>
```

Now in my database.yml file I have already put user and password in and remembered to put the integerpassword in "" and a space between the colon and the password itself like:

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
# 
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: simplelogin
  password: "1234"
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

I have even tried switching the "localhost" with the ip as described here (same problem): [Rails development - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792862/rails-development-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061)

But when I do that I don't get any messages in return from the commandline.

So why can't I connect to the database?
Would appreciate any help! Thanks! Trying to learn ruby and the whole installationsprocess has already eaten up lots of hours...

Comment: Please update the question with the content of `config/database.yml`. The error seems to suggest rake can't connect with the server but did you create the database? Do you have the same error when you run `rake db:setup` or `rake db:reset`?

Comment: The question has been updated with database.yml code. I have created the database, I just double checked with SHOW DATABASES; and the "simple_cms_development" is listed.

Comment: Just tried the rake db:setup and rake db:reset, still can't connect to mysql server on localhost (10061).

Comment: Have you started the database service? Type `mysqladmin version` and find out.

Comment: Says:C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\simple_cms>mysqladmin version
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Comment: Don't know where it gets the odbc from?

Comment: Check the mysql access log and see if ruby connects at all and if yes, if it is a permission error. I have no idea where it is on Windows. Google it.

Comment: where do I access that? I have been googling and fiddling with this question for hours now, and it feels lame to spend so much time on connection issues like this... Might give up on mysql and try something else...

Comment: Can you connect to the database manually with those parameters?

Comment: You likely have reasons for using Windows; you may want to try Ubuntu dual boot, or VirtualBox, or VMWare. In general you'll get many more people able to help you by using a these, and more people will know how to find common file locations, ports, db connectors, etc.

Comment: @tehgeekmeister just tried connecting with the "odbc" and no password, getting same message about can't connect. Might try vmware ubuntu as suggested.

Comment: I meant could you connect to the database directly, without using rails?

Comment: using just "mysql -u simplelogin -p" and entering the password afterwords works fine. I can also see the databases (usin "show databases")

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using the mysql command and using a connector is that mysql can have different default parameters based on how it is configured, making it difficult to know what is going on.

You should look for a file called my.cnf (or my.ini if you're on Windows).  It can specify a different port or host.  You're lucky that you are able to connect to the database through mysql because you can see where you are actually connected.

Take a look at your port:

```
mysql> show variables like 'port';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'socket';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| socket        | /tmp/mysql.sock |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'hostname';
+---------------+-------------+
| Variable_name | Value       |
+---------------+-------------+
| hostname      | myhostname  |
+---------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See if these values match up with the database.yml file.

Once you have these values, you can try to telnet on that port.  If there is nothing listening on that port you'll get something like:

```
$ telnet localhost 11111
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
Trying fe80::1...
telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

but if there is a connection, you'll see some junk with "mysql" written somewhere:

```
$ telnet localhost 3306
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
J
5.5.28JzKEXl7?5e|bUcq/5\Q^mysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.
```

I work on Unix, so your output may look different.

Comment: Looked up the port and it is 3306. First tried to telnet "localhost 11111", but it could not open the connection. Using port "3306" instead gave the above junk as described: ">
 5.1.67-community!^K=1z59☻J8z"5#NB@Xz~

Connection to host lost.

Press any key to continue..."        But it looses the connection immediately.

Comment: Could only find the port in the my.ini file, not socket or hostname, just a lot of comments about myisam, buffer etc.

Comment: So we know that the mysql server is in the right place.  If the host is on localhost, it's probably accessing it through a socket file and not through TCP.  You can add this to your database.yml file:
`socket: /the/socket/path/mysql.sock`.

Where the socket path is what you saw in the variable.  This way rails will use the same file as mysql.  This misalignment can happen if you install rails before mysql.

Comment: Where do I find the mysql.sock file on windows? I tried changing "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" and typed the "rake db:schema:dump", I don't get a mysql connection error, but just an empty line, but I can see it has created a schema.rb file, so maybe that was the error?

Comment: Just do `show variables like 'socket'` on your mysql prompt.  That'll tell you where the socket path is located.

Comment: Really appreciate the help, seems like a great place. I am completely new to this, so I am not sure I understand the above, but in the commandline I typed `mysql show variables like 'socket'` and it gives a list of variables including 'socket' with 'no default value'. But anyway I have kind of given up on windows. I installed ubuntu and everything seems to work fine there.

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same Lynda course.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  socket: C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I'm on Windows 8 and using mysql with the XAMPP package.

I have tried everything, and what really fixed it was the change from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this issue for a few days, tried nearly every solution available on internet.
Finally I am able to solve that error by adding port:3306 and restarting WEBrick server using 'rails server' command.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this hideous thing in Ruby and in the command line!

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

If the solutions above doesn't work, I suspect it could be a problem related to the lack MySQL services running. Rails cannot access MySQL, unless you solve the bug of MySQL.

DIAGNOSIS

Before trying the solution below, go to the command line and try to access MySQL once again from the bin folder:
    mysql -u username -p

If you get something like this:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

Then try this:

1. Run the cmd as administrator (if you can't you must consult with your IT representative)
2. Go to the bin folder in MySQL and install MySQL services using the following command:
  mysqld --install
  You can receive any of these 2 messages:
  The service already exists!
  OR
  The service was sucessfully installed
  Don't close the cmd!
3. Search for "Services"
4. Once you've opened "Services" select MySQL and click "start".
5. From the command line try to access mysql again as unidentified user, as root or as simple_cms. 
       mysql -u simplelogin -p
  If you are successful, then try to run rails again